# Preventing mistouches of links in Android web interfaces

Tags: android, iphone, mobile

I have developed a smartphone web interface for a website. On Android handsets, when a user clicks a button link, sometimes his finger will touch two buttons. For instance, in the below example, if he touches the bottom of the View Profile button, he'll also touch the Hide Profile button.

[image: Example]

This will trigger two onclick events being fired: first for the View Profile and then the Hide Profile, resulting in him going to the Hide Profile page. How can I ensure the user follows the first link?

I've tried having the onclick function for the Hide Profile link return false, but this also aborts the View Profile request, resulting in the user staying on the same page.

Answer (score 0):

When touch the show button, why not disable the hide button for 0.5 second at the same time.

I did this for the next track button.